# Installer for Java Spring Boot service

Tags: java, spring-boot, installation

I have a Java Spring Boot application which I would like to run as a service, ideally in Mac, Windows and Linux.  It should run 24/7 and be robust i.e. restart itself if it crashes.

Does anyone know the current best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: Deploy it in a Docker container.

Comment: what about using Eurekia ( https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) - spawn multiple nodes - then monitor them with f.e nagios

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an app as a service it should confront to some Interface defined by Microsoft. Here it is:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685942(v=vs.85).aspx

This is not the easiest solution and will make you app platform dependent. There are some wrappers that make what you want possible.

Check the Java Service Wrapper
https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html

It has options to wrap the app as windows service and unix daemon. I am not sure about macOs. There are other similar wrappers too

Answer (score 0):

Best practice<sup>1</sup> is to use the best practice solution for each platform.  Unfortunately, that means different things for different platforms; e.g.

- on Window, use the Windows Service mechanism
- on UNIX / Linux, write a service script that uses the distro's native "init" framework
- on Mac OSX, you typically use something like Automator to create a ZIP file that implements the service.

Unfortunately, in the UNIX / Linux case there are a number of different init frameworks, depending on the vintage; see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).

Another answer mentions the [Java Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html).  I don't know how well it works with different Linux "init" frameworks, but it looks like it provides a one-size-fits-all init script written in "sh".  It should be usable with `systemd`, though you won't get the full benefits of that framework.

---

<sup>1 - But read James Bach's [No Best Practices](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27) article.</sup>